# django data model for system page visits

Tags: django, django-models

I am newbie at django and building a small project in which I have users, users belong to groups and pages.

Now I want to log whenever a users logs into the system and every page he visits.

I also want to be able to give him access to the pages either based on the group he belongs to or based on his ID.

I have the following code written so far, and I am stuck at the idea of giving him group/ID based access.

```
class userProfile(models.Model):
        user            = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
        uniID           = models.CharField(max_length=6)

class systemEntry(models.Model):
        user    = models.ManyToMany(userProfile)
        time    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class pageProfile(models.Model):
        url     = models.URLField()
        name    = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        parent  = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        createdOn= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        access ??

class pageVisit(models.Model):
        user    = models.ManyToMany(userProfile)
        page    = models.ManyToMany(pageProfile)
        time    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I was thinking of 2 possible ways:

1) create 2 other classes. First groupPageAccess and IDpageAccess. Didn't know how to match to userID and groupID

2) Their should be a way to do it from within pageProfile. But also didn't know how

I appreciate any criticism for the code above and help to know how to think about writing models.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to authorisation, I personally use django-guardian
It allows you to automate per-user authorisation process.

I think that I don't have to give you examples, because docs are very good:
https://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/stable/userguide/index.html

When it comes to logging, it's well described in django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/